chrome manifest v3 request headers add -- v2 to v3
I looked at this 1 year old post
With chrome Manifest v3 how can I add custom fields to request headers
is there any update to this? Any easy way to add headers (my situation is exactly the same)
I need to add headers to websocket (local one) and add headers to an external website (whitelisted)
Can anyone be generous to point me to a sample code on how to get this done in v3
(to my woes -- google one-sided push on v3 is taxing and it should make some automated tool to do this conversion v2 to v3)
Thanks in advance for answering.

My two cents are that this is the last feature Google will ever allow. Reacting to web requests from JavaScript is what allowed uBlock Origin to be so effective, and that directly goes against Google's interests. If there is any feature that Google wanted to kill with v3, it's this.
